# How to check if keys are twice or more in a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I made a function which converts a list into a dict. Now i want to check if they are the same length and if they have keys which appear twice.

```
def make_dict(keys, values):
    if len(keys) == len(values):
        return dict(zip(keys, values))
    else:
        None
```

I want to check these 3 lists. The first should be true, the second and third one false.

```
make_dict([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])

make_dict([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'])

make_dict([1, 1], ['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: There are no duplicates key in dictionary

Comment: make_dict([1, 1], ['a', 'b']) would result in 1:a and 1:b. i cant figure out how my function can test this scenario so no key is used twice.

Comment: @MarcelHlmn no it wouldn't, try it and see.

Comment: `len(set(l)) == len(l)` will be true for a list `l` if each element only occurs once. in case this question is an instance of "looking before you leap"

Answer (score 1):

You want to checking, that the parameters to `make_dict` are valid:

```
def make_dict(keys, values):
    if len(keys) != len(values):
        raise ValueError("keys and values have different length")
    result = dict(zip(keys, values))
    if len(result) != len(keys):
        raise ValueError("there are duplicate keys")
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you! Got everything i want. Im just starting with python and programming at all. The name result can be anythin else right ? It just defines the dict, which is made?

Comment: `result` is only a variable name, which is pretty generic for the result of a function.